# Bluetooth keyboard does not autoconnect after reboot

Tags: bluetooth

I am using a logitech harmony remote which is recognized as a bluetooth keyboard
it works flawlessly but if i reboot my computer (ubuntu 15.04) it does not auto connect. I have to manually reconnect the device from the bluetooth menu.
any solution for that?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Once the computer advertises on bluetooth as long as the keyboards profile exists and is saved. The keyboard must automatically issue the reconnect. It's usually the devices responsibility to reconnect to a previously connected host.

Maybe your computer is not advertising on bluetooth on startup. Maybe the keyboards profile is not being saved. Those things should probably be ruled out first.

Comment: Can you plz describe further what do you mean by advertising on bluetooth? I see the profile of the keyboard configured and paired on the bluetooth setting menu but it's still not connected. I have to click "connect" manually

Comment: Ok, when your computer's bluetooth first turns on, it will announce itself if discover mode  is on. The devices you have will ping its list of devices it's pair to by  physical ID(MAC address) every X seconds as so to try to reconnect. There are master and slave devices. Your computer is a master device and your keyboard is a slave device. This might help you understand further and troubleshoot the process. https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bluetooth-basics

Comment: I observe the same under Ubuntu 16.04 with the Logitech K380. Did you find a solution?